# Electromagnet to Permanent magnet strength conversion

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there a formula wherein you can compare the strength of a permanent magnet to that of an electro magnet. Specifically, if I have a permanent magnet that has say 100 lbs of pull, how would I create an electro magnet with the same pull?

Answer (score -1):

There is no easy formula because the geometry of an electromagnet is necessarily different from that of a permanent magnet, after all, in an electromagnet we need some volume to place the windings in, which disrupts the magnetic field. Having said that, there are some basic relationships that a magnet designer will need to know about and the design procedure (usually using magnetics design software) will be somewhat similar.

For a practical approach at gauging the real-world relationship (which undoubtedly exists as a coarse performance ratio), I would suggest that you find yourself a range of technical products by looking at lift magnet catalogs. The manufacturers will specify the lift performance of their products and they will usually also give you the mass (or weight) and the size of the product. If you take the time to plot the mass/volume vs. the lift capacity, you should get several sets of curves that should be somewhat parallel for electromagnets and for equivalent (or at least similar) permanent magnet based products. One can then calculate a ratio estimate  between the two.

This procedure is being used in the real world quite a bit to make engineering budget estimates for solutions that are trying to achieve the same goal with solutions that are not directly comparable. It builds on real-world performance data rather than on theoretical estimates because real-world performance is something that has positively been achieved and it's easy to come by, while theoretical performance is both speculative and often requires a significant amount of work to calculate.

Save yourself the work, at least for now, and try to do an analysis of hands-on, for-sale products. That way you will get a feeling for what can and can not be done with these products in the real world. You will also earn bragging rights because this is what "real engineers" and physicists who work as engineers do.